# Is it possible to get the container DOM element passed to React.render before the contents are overwritten?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a DOM element, `container`, into which I want to have React render.

```
<div id="container">
  <input id="ae06f4ec-5ce9-11e5-9f3f-0021cc62b713" class="child"/>
</div>
```

The `container` element already has some children with attributes that I need to preserve:  I need to keep the id of the child input.

When I call `React.render(myReactElement, document.getElementById('container'))`, is it possible for me to get the `container` DOM element from within my component before render overwrites the contents, so I can then get the id and store it as state?

I tried calling `getDOMNode` on the component in `componentWillMount`, but I get

```
Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.
```

I'm trying to avoid having to pass in the input's id as a prop.  (This is a simplified example.  I'm looking for a solution that scales to multiple children of the container element.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a way to get the container contents before rendering from inside the component, so I don't think you'll be able to get away from using props. However, that doesn't mean you have to pass the *data* as props; you can simply capture the DOM nodes and pass *them* as props, letting the component do the work. For example:

```javascript
function render(elem, container) {
  // Pass the container's children (as DOM nodes) to the top-level component
  var cloned = React.cloneElement(elem, {originalChildren: container.children})
  React.render(cloned, container);
}

var Application = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    // Convert the NodeList to an Array.
    var originalChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.props.originalChildren);
    var ids = originalChildren.map(node => {
      return node.getAttribute("id");
    });

    return {
      ids: ids
    };
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        The IDs are: {this.state.ids.map(id => <div>{id}</div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// Now we call `render` with the same parameters we would have
// used for `React.render`; no need to do anything special.
render(<Application />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Here's this code [working in a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rihamu/edit?html,js,output): https://jsbin.com/rihamu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like a reasonable approach.